# FTP Virtual Directory entry in registry in server 2008

Tags: iis-7, ftp

I am migrating my application from server 2003 to server 2008 and facing an issue related to FTP service. If I add a virtual directory within FTP in 2003, I can access the same via code from registry using
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\MSFTPSVC\Parameters\Virtual Roots

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey objRegKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine;
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey objRegKeyLoc = objRegKey.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\ControlSet001\\Services\\MSFTPSVC\\Parameters\\Virtual Roots");            
System.String strDocumentPath = objRegKeyLoc.GetValue("/Documents").ToString();
```

but this behavior is missing in server 2008. The path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\MSFTPSVC\Parameters" is available but the next key "Virtual Roots" is missing. Should I add it manually on every server or there is something I am not aware of? Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. I have to manually add the "Virtual Roots" directory within the registry and the path of my FTP virtual directories. The only bad thing is: I have to do this on every client server.